# Waking up the VPN server on demand using WOL

Tags: vpn, wake-on-lan, wake-on-demand

I am planning to setup a small lab at home. For this I am debating to get a s/w or a h/w based VPN. One of the main concern in power usage. H/w based VPN doesn't consume much, while s/w based VPN does. This query is about s/w based VPN.

For the s/w based VPN, I don't want to keep the VPN server up and running all the time. I was thinking of [WOL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) to start the VPN server and then connect to the VPN to access the home network. For sending the WOL magic packet, I need to configure port forwarding in the router to the VPN server.

I can't think of any problem in this approach, but would like to know the experience of others with the same.

Comment: You could use a low power device like a Raspberry Pi to host your always-on VPN

Comment: I found a nice article for installing openvpn on Raspberry Pi. It looks fun. Any idea on number of concurrent users it can support?

Comment: If I remember well there are routers on the market with VPN support. https://www.howtogeek.com/221001/how-to-set-up-your-own-home-vpn-server/